# Excel VBA if "x", then select rows and paste to another sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I'm stuck attempting to develop a fairly basic accounting spreadsheet for a work project. I'm not sure how to add attachments here, so I will try explain as best as I can.

Every day I manually enter data into a sheet with several columns, a few examples of column headings I have are: `Tax Invoice No.`, `Customer`, `Description`, and `Date`. They range from cells `A3` to `Y3`, with the table covering the range `A3:Y1135`.

I need to establish a front page report for others to easily read the data, but which also allows me to populate: either `Current Month Results` or `Previous Month Results` or `Year to date results`, whichever I select. I know there are plenty of manual ways to go about this, but am hoping to get some opinions from people far more advanced with this than me! I'm thinking a macro button or a drop down box to generate the reports might work, but I am stuck.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

No need for VBA. Use a pivot table (hide the sheet) to merge the data and if you require further customisation, use GetPivotData function to pull exact fields ... referencing external cells in the GetPivotData function will allow the viewer to filter ... Can use something like a combobox, list, or even data validation to for selection...

Answer (score 0):

I would say you can do this with standard excel formulas and not have to bother with VBA. Without having more detail its hard to give an exact answer but I would go along the lines of working out what time periods you want to report on and then using either the SUMIF function or SUMPRODUCT if you are using multiple criteria to get your summary page. If you want to lookup vales instead of adding ranges together take a look at VLOOKUP

Answer (score 0):

```
 Sheets("Output").Select
Range("A2").Select
Name2 = ActiveCell.Value
Do While Name2 <> ""
Sheets("Master Table").Select
Range("A2").Select
name1 = ActiveCell.Value
Do While name1 <> ""
 If name1 = Name2 Then
      ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
      Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Copy
      Sheets("Output").Select
      ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
       ActiveCell.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
      'ActiveSheet.paste
      Application.CutCopyMode = False
      Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToLeft)).Select
      'ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
      name1 = ""
  Else
    Sheets("Master Table").Select
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    name1 = ActiveCell.Value

End If
Loop
Sheets("Output").Select
 ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    Name2 = ActiveCell.Value
Loop
```